# Decoding File to Bitmap sometimes works and sometimes does not

Tags: android, bitmap, android-file

I am using [EasyImage](https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage) library to take pictures.
I then convert those Files to Bitmap and then I convert Bitmap to Base64 and upload it to server.
I know, it's not a good way to do it, but that's how I currently do it.

When a picture is taken:

```
@Override
public void onImagePicked(File imageFile, EasyImage.ImageSource source) {
    uploadImage(imageFile);
}
```

This is the first line inside "uploadImage" method:

```
Image image = new Image(LoginManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUsername(), file);
```

This is the constructor:

```
public Image(String userName, File imageFile) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.imageFile = imageFile;

    createBase64(getBitmap());
}
```

Inside "getBitmap" is where the problem begins. These 2 lines in particular:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getPath());
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, false);
```

imageFile is **never** null.
I checked with debugger at least a 100 times and it is never null. It also always has path.
`getPath()` is never null.
However, it still often fails to create bitmap.

Sometimes it is successful and everything is OK, but most of the times, the bitmap is null.
I don't know why.
File (the picture taken) is always created successfully and is never null, but it just fails to create the Bitmap for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String))

> **Returns**
>   the resulting decoded bitmap, or null if it could not be decoded.

This can have various reasons, most of the times the bitmap is too large and the space could not be allocated.

Check that the path to the image exists and that you have read / write permissions to the URI specified.

If you do have access but it is still failing you should add `BitmapFactory.Options` to the method call and set `inSampleSize` to load a smaller version of the image.

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

Also you should always check for `null` returned when working with bitmaps, since memory can always be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've set inSampleSize to 4 (also tried 8) but it sadly still doesn't work. Same problem. Do you have any other ideas what could have gone wrong?

Comment: @Whiz Check your LogCat for possible output before / after the call. Make sure the uri / path exists and that you have read / write access, further than that...hard to tell

Comment: When you mentioned "read / write access", I went to check under my app info (on phone) and saw that I only had CAMERA permission granted, but not STORAGE. I granted storage permission, went back to app and now it works 100% of the time. Why was this happening though? Shouldn't the app crash when you try to do something without permission? And why did it sometimes (very rarely) actually still work? I am very confused by this. But anyway, thanks a lot! Feel free to add the permission thing in your answer and I will gladly accept it :)

Comment: @Whiz it is strange that it sometimes worked.. but it could easily be that bitmap factory handles the "no access" exception and just return null, like specified. I updated the answer, thanks